# Duplicating layer properties in ArcGIS Online

Tags: layers, symbology, arcgis-online, duplication

I'm very new to ArcGIS. I was wondering if there is a way to duplicate layer properties (drawing style/legend and pop-ups) to another layer. I was thinking, maybe duplicating the layer, then changing the source, but I couldn't find a way to do that either. I'm using ArcGIS Online and my source is a polygon layer from a feature layer file online. In some of my cases, the data column/variables are the exactly the same, just a different map location (seems more feasible for these cases). I was surprised I couldn't find anything online, but I could just be phrasing my question wrong.

Comment: Access the layer stored up on agol directly from within arcpro, this will bring down the symbology then save that out as a layer file?

Comment: @Hornbydd Ahh, so there no way to do it within ArcGIS Online strictly?

Comment: After looking up copying layer symbology I've come across a suggestion using JSON (but I have no idea how to apply the JSON drawinginfo onto a layer). https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/vector-tile-style-editor/editing-json/
And I've also seen documentation (Update vector tile layer style) on the esri website but am unable to find the "Save style as" window. https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/update-vector-tile-style.htm

Comment: https://assistant.esri-ps.com/content?queryScope=USER&folder=allmycontent&num=20&start=1&sortField=modified&sortOrder=desc

Comment: @YogeshChavan sorry for the late comment, but thanks for the link to edit the JSON!